# Validar un campo de tipo Float acepte ceros despues de un punto decimal en SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Estoy usando el orm Sqlalchemy, cuando ingreso un dato de tipo `Float` o `Numeric` no acepta ceros, ejemplo:

```
price = 12.0231 
price = 12.1021
price = 12.0012
```

Los anteriores, si guarda los ceros

El problema es cuando los ceros van al ultimo

```
price = 12.1100 o price = 12.110
```

En la base de datos no guarda ceros

Lo estoy declarando de esta manera:

`price = Column(Float((8,4), asdecimal=False), nullable=False)`

`price = Column(Numeric(8,4), nullable=False)`

Alguna idea o sugerecia?

Comment: Hola, a pesar de que no los está guardando no veo un problema real detrás de esto. Es decir, podrían haber mil ceros a la derecha y eso no va a cambiar el número: `12.1100000000000000` sigue siendo `12.11`, a diferencia de los ceros a la izquierda: `12.001` es diferente a `12.0001`. Por otro lado, me parece que es un tema de tu RDBMS más que otra cosa. Prueba obteniendo los datos desde una consola.

Answer (score 0):

El ORM o la base de datos van a tratar de almacenar la información de la forma más eficiente posible.

Si declaras una columna de este modo:

```
price = Column(Numeric(8,4), nullable=False)
```

Estas dos sentencias son equivalentes:

```
price = 1.10
price = 1.1
```

Y por tanto lo guardará de la forma más eficiente que pueda. El typemod `4` del [Numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) sólo indica el número máximo de decimales que se almacenerán en el campo

Supongo que lo que tu quieres es que tus números siempre tengan un determinado formato, por ejemplo cuatro decimales, en la interfaz que presentas a tus usuarios. Pero esto es un problema de como formateas ese número. Si por ejemplo es una aplicación web, puedes devolver el número tal cual si es una API JSON REST y formatearlo en el cliente con javascript.